# Matplotlib savefig does not save the full plot in the output

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, figsize

I'm making visualisations and when i save plots i don't get the full plot in my output.

My plots are limited by 24 hours, in the image bellow there is only the part between [20:40,00:00]

i fixed a figsize of (155,3) and DPI = 300

i know that the size is high, DPI too, but i need that.

[image]

How can i save figures and getting full plot on the output.

PS : if i reduce the figsize and the DPI it works but i need to get it with that figsize.

Thanks.

Comment: `plt.savefig(filename, bbox_inches="tight", dpi=300)` Would it be an improvement if

Comment: @r-beginners I have done this already but still no improvement

Comment: What do you mean by it does not save the image?  What type of image are you trying to make?

Comment: @JodyKlymak, i can visualise my plot in my notebook with %inline
so as i needed to save it as an image i found out that the output is not the same with my plot. 
I'm saving my plot as a JPEG file.
it you have another question tell me.
thanks